# Debugger stops when debugging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I am making a spreadsheet for a class.   In the code below there is the unit tests, spreadsheet class, cell class, dependency graph class.  I am trying to debug my program and watch what happens with setCellContents method in my spreadsheet class.    I start the debug and create a sheet object and add cells to it.   Everything works great until I try to look at the cell variables inside of the sheet in the little local variables menu.  As soon as I click on the little drop down arrow to see whats inside the cell object, the program stops the debugging and crashes saying:

The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. Check the execution process logs for more information.

### THIS IS THE UNIT TEST CLASS

```
 using System;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using SS;
    using Dependencies;
    using Formulas;

    namespace SpreadSheetTests
    {
         [TestClass]
         public class SpreadSheetTests
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Tests the addition of two cells and whether the 
        /// dependency graph of the sheet graph works properly
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod()]
        public void getCellNamesTest()
        {
            AbstractSpreadsheet sheet = new SpreadSheet();
            sheet.SetCellContents("A1", 4);


            //SetCellContents will create a cell in the spreadsheet.cs class and will 
            //add the cell to the dictionary and the dependency graph possibly

            Formula formula = new Formula("A1 + 5");
            sheet.SetCellContents("A2", formula);
           //The name of the cell in the contents of A2 matches the name of A1
            //So A2 depends on A1

            Formula form1 = new Formula("A1 + A2");
            sheet.SetCellContents("A3", form1);

            //MORE WORK TO BE DONE ON THIS ONE TO GET IT WORKING

             Assert.AreEqual(9, sheet.GetCellContents("A3"));
        }
       }
}



    THIS IS THE SPREADSHEET CLASS

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dependencies;
using Formulas;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SS
{
    public class SpreadSheet : AbstractSpreadsheet
    {
        //Private data members of the Spreadsheet class
        private Dictionary<string, Cell> sheet;
        private DependencyGraph graph;

        /// <summary>
        /// Spreadsheet Constructor
        /// Creates an empty spreadsheet
        /// </summary>
        public SpreadSheet()
        {
            sheet = new Dictionary<string, Cell>();
            graph = new DependencyGraph();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Enumerates the names of all the non-empty cells in the spreadsheet.
        /// </summary>
        public override IEnumerable<String> GetNamesOfAllNonemptyCells()
        {
            HashSet<string> cellNames = new HashSet<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.Count; i++ )
            {/*
                if(sheet[i].CellContents)
                {

                }*/
            }

                    return cellNames;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// If name is null or invalid, throws an InvalidNameException.
        /// 
        /// Otherwise, returns the contents (as opposed to the value) of the named cell.  The return
        /// value should be either a string, a double, or a Formula.
        public override object GetCellContents(String name)
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(name, @"[a-zA-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*") || name == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidNameException();
            }
            else
            {
                if (sheet[name] != null)
                {
                    return sheet[name].CellContents;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;//don't know if this will work.  test
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// If name is null or invalid, throws an InvalidNameException.
        /// 
        /// Otherwise, the contents of the named cell becomes number.  The method returns a
        /// set consisting of name plus the names of all other cells whose value depends, 
        /// directly or indirectly, on the named cell.
        /// 
        /// For example, if name is A1, B1 contains A1*2, and C1 contains B1+A1, the
        /// set {A1, B1, C1} is returned.
        /// </summary>
        public override ISet<String> SetCellContents(String name, double number)
        {
            HashSet<string> dependentSet = new HashSet<string>();

           //Check to see if the cell name is valid
           // A string is a cell name if and only if it consists of one or more letters, 
           // followed by a non-zero digit, followed by zero or more digits.
            if(!Regex.IsMatch(name, @"[a-zA-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*") || name == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidNameException();
            }
            else
            {
                //Name is valid and the cell is created
                Cell cell = new Cell(name, number);

                //Now the cell is put into the dictionary for quick reference
                sheet.Add(cell.CellName, cell);

                //Check to see if the cell is dependant on any other cells
                //If it is return a set of the name of the cell and all the other
                //cells that it is dependant on
                if(graph.HasDependents(cell.CellName))
                {
                    dependentSet.Add(cell.CellName);
                    foreach(string value in graph.GetDependents(cell.CellName))
                    {
                        dependentSet.Add(value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dependentSet.Add(cell.CellName);
                }
            }

            return dependentSet;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// If text is null, throws an ArgumentNullException.
        /// 
        /// Otherwise, if name is null or invalid, throws an InvalidNameException.
        /// 
        /// Otherwise, the contents of the named cell becomes text.  The method returns a
        /// set consisting of name plus the names of all other cells whose value depends, 
        /// directly or indirectly, on the named cell.
        /// 
        /// For example, if name is A1, B1 contains A1*2, and C1 contains B1+A1, the
        /// set {A1, B1, C1} is returned.
        /// </summary>
        public override ISet<String> SetCellContents(String name, String text)
        {
            if(text == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            HashSet<string> dependentSet = new HashSet<string>();

            //Check to see if the cell name is valid
            // A string is a cell name if and only if it consists of one or more letters, 
            // followed by a non-zero digit, followed by zero or more digits.
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(name, @"[a-zA-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*") || name == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidNameException();
            }
            else
            {
                //Name is valid and the cell is created
                Cell cell = new Cell(name, text);

                //Now the cell is put into the dictionary for quick reference
                sheet.Add(cell.CellName, cell);

                //Check to see if the cell is dependant on any other cells
                //If it is return a set of the name of the cell and all the other
                //cells that it is dependant on
                if (graph.HasDependents(cell.CellName))
                {
                    dependentSet.Add(cell.CellName);
                    foreach (string value in graph.GetDependents(cell.CellName))
                    {
                        dependentSet.Add(value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dependentSet.Add(cell.CellName);
                }
            }

            return dependentSet;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// If formula parameter is null, throws an ArgumentNullException.
        /// 
        /// Otherwise, if name is null or invalid, throws an InvalidNameException.
        /// 
        /// Otherwise, if changing the contents of the named cell to be the formula would cause a 
        /// circular dependency, throws a CircularException.
        /// 
        /// Otherwise, the contents of the named cell becomes formula.  The method returns a
        /// Set consisting of name plus the names of all other cells whose value depends,
        /// directly or indirectly, on the named cell.
        /// 
        /// For example, if name is A1, B1 contains A1*2, and C1 contains B1+A1, the
        /// set {A1, B1, C1} is returned.
        /// </summary>
        public override ISet<String> SetCellContents(String name, Formula formula)
        {
             HashSet<string> dependentSet = new HashSet<string>();
            //NEED TO ADD THE CIRCULAR DEPENDENCY EXCEPTION CHECK!!!!!!!!!!!!
            //---------------------------------------------------------------
            //---------------------------------------------------------------
            /*if(forula makes a circular dependancy)
            {
                throw new CircularException();
            }*/

            if(formula == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            //Check to see if the cell name is valid
            // A string is a cell name if and only if it consists of one or more letters, 
            // followed by a non-zero digit, followed by zero or more digits.
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(name, @"[a-zA-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*") || name == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidNameException();
            }
            else
            {
                //Name is valid and the cell is created
                Cell cell = new Cell(name, formula);

                //Now the cell is put into the dictionary for quick reference
                sheet.Add(cell.CellName, cell);

                Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s");
                string[] cellString = regex.Split(cell.CellContents.ToString());

                //ONLY HAS DEPENDANTS IF THERE IS A FORMULA
                //Check to see if the cell depends on any othere cells by checking
                //for any matching regular expressions in the cells contents
               foreach(string match in cellString)
               {
                   if (Regex.IsMatch(match, @"[a-zA-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*"))
                   {
                       graph.AddDependency(name, match);
                   }
               }

                //NOT SURE IF THIS IS RIGHT TEST IT
                //---------------------------------
                //Check to see if the cell is dependant on any other cells
                //If it is return a set of the name of the cell and all the other
                //cells that it is dependant on
                if (graph.HasDependents(cell.CellName))
                {
                    dependentSet.Add(cell.CellName);
                    foreach (string value in graph.GetDependents(cell.CellName))
                    {
                        dependentSet.Add(value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dependentSet.Add(cell.CellName);
                }
            }

            return dependentSet;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// If name is null, throws an ArgumentNullException.
        /// 
        /// Otherwise, if name isn't a valid cell name, throws an InvalidNameException.
        /// 
        /// Otherwise, returns an enumeration, without duplicates, of the names of all cells whose
        /// values depend directly on the value of the named cell.  In other words, returns
        /// an enumeration, without duplicates, of the names of all cells that contain
        /// formulas containing name.
        /// 
        /// For example, suppose that
        /// A1 contains 3
        /// B1 contains the formula A1 * A1
        /// C1 contains the formula B1 + A1
        /// D1 contains the formula B1 - C1
        /// The direct dependents of A1 are B1 and C1
        /// </summary>
        protected override IEnumerable<String> GetDirectDependents(String name)
        {
            HashSet<string> dependants = new HashSet<string>();

            if(name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            if(!(Regex.IsMatch(name, @"[a-zA-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*")))
            {
                throw new InvalidNameException();
            }

            foreach(string cellName in graph.GetDependents(name))
            {
                dependants.Add(cellName);
            }

            return dependants;
        }
    }
}



THIS IS THE CELL CLASS

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Formulas;

namespace SS
{
    public class Cell
    {
         //Private data members of the cell class
        private string cellName;
        private object cellContents;
        private object cellValue;


        /// <summary>
        /// Cell Constructor
        /// Creates a Cell with a string in it
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cellName"></param>
        /// <param name="word"></param>
        public Cell(string cellName, string word)
        {
            this.cellName = cellName;
            this.cellContents = word;
            this.cellValue = word;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Cell Constructor
        /// Creates a cell with a number in it
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cellName"></param>
        /// <param name="cellNum"></param>
        public Cell(string cellName, double cellNumber)
        {
            this.cellName = cellName;
            this.cellValue = cellNumber;
            this.cellContents = cellNumber;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cell Constructor
        /// Creates a cell with a formula in it
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cellName"></param>
        /// <param name="cellFormula"></param>
        /// type object holds double, formula, string
        public Cell(string _cellName, Formula formula)
        {
            cellName = _cellName;
            cellContents = formula;
            //this.cellValue = this will be a calculated double in future assignements
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the cell name
        /// </summary>
        public string CellName
        {
            get{ return cellName; }
            set { cellName = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the cell word
        /// </summary>
        public string CellWord
        {
            get { return CellWord; }
            set { CellWord = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the cell number
        /// </summary>
        public object CellContents
        {
            get { return cellContents; }
            set { cellContents = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the cell formula
        /// </summary>
        public object CellValue
        {
            get { return cellValue; }
            set { cellValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is SpreadSheet using Excel Interop?

Comment: no it is not using that

Comment: Did you enable [MS Test Logs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2013/01/25/how-to-enable-mstest-logs.aspx)? If not, enable it and then try again. If it fails again you can see the log. Also try to do it that way Test>Debug>All Tests in Solution.